# Kubernetes view services monitor

Tags: docker, kubernetes, prometheus, prometheus-operator

I am new to Kubernetes. I created a service monitor, I am wondering how can I find the created service monitor.
The service monitor is created successfully.
[image]

When I use `kubectl get services`, I can't find the created service monitor. Can i get some help?

Thanks!

Comment: I can't run your reproduction scenario (please include actual text in your questions and not screenshots of terminal windows) but that output looks like it's creating a separate custom resource object and not a standard Kubernetes Service.  Try `kubectl get servicemonitors`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ServiceMonitor is a custom resource provided by the Prometheus Operator and it's name inside Kubernetes is `servicemonitor`. So you have to list you ServiceMonitors with:

```sh
kubectl get servicemonitors
```

Or you can list the specific ServiceMonitor you created with:

```sh
kubectl get servicemonitor servicemonitor-sms-config-services
```